# making non-PyPI package available in virtualenv from local install

Tags: python, virtualenv

Say I have a virtualenv instance and I have a set of packages installed in that environment. Now say that I want to install another package that is not in the PyPI, i.e. not available with pip or easy_install, and these are installed locally, not system-wide. What do I do if I want to make such a package available in the virtual environment, without including system site-packages, just that one package/module?

Answer (score 1):

you can type

```
 pip install -e .
```

in a directory containing a `setup.py`.